# Azure storage account rejects the issuer of a managed service identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

I'm [using the Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication library (v1.0.3) for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity#asal) to connect from Azure Function app to blob storage using managed service identity. Auth code:

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");
var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
var credentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
var storageUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net");
var client = new CloudBlobClient(storageUri, credentials);
```

One existing storage account refuses to accept the MSI regardless of given RBAC roles:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request.
Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Additional exception details of `storageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.AdditionalDetails` complain that `AuthenticationErrorDetail: Issuer validation failed. Issuer did not match.`

When decoding the failing jwt token, the issuer seems ok:

```
{
  "aud": "https://storage.azure.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<my directory guid>/",
  ...
}
```

When I created new identically set up storage accounts then the same function app MSI and auth code worked and even the issuer in token were exactly the same. So the client function app and it's MSI identity are not the culprit here.

**Why does this one storage account fail to authorize and how to get it to accept the MSI?**

**UPDATE:** [Cross posted to MS forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49a4469b-50f0-4e2b-9c38-ba3bf30fb69b/possible-bug-azure-storage-account-rejects-the-issuer-of-a-managed-service-identity?forum=windowsazuredata) to get MS attention in verifying if this is an azure bug.

Comment: Did you have an access policy of the blob storage container?

Comment: If the issuer contains the id for the AAD where your storage account's subscription is connected, then this sounds like a bug on the Storage side. Remember it's a preview ;)

Comment: @JoyWang, no, the test container has had no access policies set.

Comment: @juunas Has a good question: Are you sure that the storage account is in an Azure subscription that is associated with the same Azure AD tenant as MSI is in?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret yes, they are in the same Azure directory. and storage account portal GUI detects the MSI account for RBAC role assignment with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after checking with MS, it is unclear what was the cause, but moving the affected subscriptions to another Azure AD directory seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Is that really a "viable solution" ?

Comment: Since there are still NO better solutions given, then this silly workaround is better than nothing. It happened to solve the problem for good in my case and this fact may help others. Hopefully just as theoretical knowledge to better assess, what the original problem might have been. I'm happy to +1 any better answers/solutions.

Comment: I have an open support incident involving this, we'll see where it goes..

Comment: @GavinStevens any update on your support incident...?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a nice quality day with this error. It might not be due to the same root cause as OP, but it might help others so I thought I'd post it here.

I was using the `DefaultAzureCredential` class to retrieve a token for my user, configured as the Azure Service Account in Visual Studio. This would then automatically switch to using the managed identity of the app server in non-localhost environments.

For my specific case, I saw that the tenant id of the issuer in the JWT did not match the tenant id of the user's objectid mentioned in the `oid` property of the JWT. This meant that a token for my user's tenant was retrieved instead of the tenant in which the resource was located. I solved this by supplying the correct tenant id in the credential options. Here's some steps:

1. Use this to retrieve and check the token used by the blob client

```
// This will try to use the VisualStudioCredential to get a token as all other options will fail
var token = await new DefaultAzureCredential().GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/.default" }));
```

Decoding this token through jwt.ms shows you the `iss` property with a value like `"https://sts.windows.net/{issuerTenantId}/"`

2. How to manually set the right tenant for the credential

```
var cred = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
{
    VisualStudioTenantId = tenantId
});

var storageclient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(url), cred);

BlobContainerClient container = _storageclient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerId);
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobId);
byte[] byteArray = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(entity);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    await blob.UploadAsync(stream, overwrite: true);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I test with your Auth code and **both existing and new created Storage account accept MSI**. So I approve with what juunas said, it may be an bug on Azure Storage.

You could go to [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to give your feedback to let developers fix it.

Comment: I agree it may be a bug. Though the provided link is intended for feature requests and voting, not bug reports. Do you happen to know a better channel for bug reports (no paid support plan on this subscription)?

Comment: Well, you  could open an issue in the [Github](https://github.com/Azure?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=).

Comment: @ImrePühvel, any process now?

Comment: Azure storage server-side does not seem to have a repo in github.